# How to run a code several times in Python automatically

Tags: python

I have a Python code `Test.py`. How do I run this code for a very large number of times, say 100, without clicking on `Run` 100 times?

Comment: you can use a for loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just copy all your code and paste it inside a function, than call the function 100 times.

```py
def function():
    // Paste your code here

for x in range(100):
    function()
```

Of course this depends on the code. I mean don't paste 2000 lines of code inside the function. Otherwise you can run code executing the command `python script/path/main.py`

```
import os

for x in range(100):
    os.system("python script/path/main.py")
```

Comment: The code is close to 10000 lines. Is there a way?

Comment: You could insert all the lines in the function but it's not a great solutions. Otherwise you can run the code from the shell. I have updated the answere

Answer (score 2):

If you need to run it not asynchronously and the task is not to edit Test.py, you can create new Main.py file and import Test.py, and then launch Main.py

Test.py:

```
def say_hello():
    print('hi')
```

Main.py:

```
import Test

for i in range(1000):
    Test.say_hello()
```

Comment: If you want to run each Test.py simultaneously (asynchronously) let me now in the comment so i write a new one

Answer (score 0):

You can create a bash script to run your code multiple times. Create `script.sh` file and add this to it:

```bash
for (( i=1; i<=100; i++ ))
do 
   python Test.py
done
```

And run it using `bash script.sh`